# I want to get the single envelope of the signal below in MATLAB but i am not sure which function will be most suitable

Tags: matlab

The signal is a waveform generated by an electromagnet placed on a sample of Q235 steel with 6mm thickness. An AE sensor is also placed on the sample to detect the waveform. The excitation frequency is 30hz and the excitation voltage is 40v. The number of samples is 2M. In the image there are 3 envelopes, I want to get the single envelope from the signal(for example the envelope in the YELLOW).

The second figure is a reference to what I want to achieve using my waveform.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What you are showing in yellow is not what is referred to as the "envelope", but regardless it sounds like you just want to extract the waveform from 0.012 seconds to 0.03 seconds?  If so, is this may help you: https://www.mathworks.com/company/technical-articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

Comment: Thank you for responding to my query. I have edited my original question and added a reference figures to show what I actually want. If you can  take a look at it and guide me, i will be thankful to you.